# Reload a glassfish desde java EE

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Estoy realizando una aplicacion en java web y ya esta montada en un servidor glassfish.

¿Existe alguna manera de que por medio de un botón o alguna función en mi aplicación pueda desplegarla nuevamente en el servidor con sus cambios? ¿Es posible?

Si es así, ¿pueden decirme alguna manera de conseguirlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No es "Java Web", es **Java EE**.
2. ¿A qué te refieres con "recargar"? Una aplicación cuando está corriendo es porque el **.war** está **desplegado** en el servidor de aplicaciones. No existe acción para el término "recargar".

Si te refieres a **redesplegar** (redeployment en inglés) desde la misma aplicación, la respuesta es no. Para desplegar una aplicación primero hay que construirla (build), sea con el *IDE* o con *Maven/Gradle* para generar el war y desplegarlo en el servidor.

#### Actualización

Bien, te refieres a *dynamic reload* de GlassFish. Bien, esta característica sirve para que cuando modifiques el código o los archivos de configuración de tu aplicación, no se haga un redesplegado total, si no que GlassFish copia los .class de las clases modificadas o los archivos de configuración modificados dentro del directorio `deployment` de dicho módulo (ver información [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4502/beadz/index.html)). Sobre si lo puedes hacer desde tu aplicación, no creo sea posible si glassfish no te provee una API para acceder al servidor en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Perdon por el error ...  a lo que me refiero es cuando tu aplicacion ya esta montado en el servidor , vas a la consolo del glassfish y luego a aplicaciones . despues cuando la aplicacion ya esta te aparece ............Launch | Redeploy | Reload   <- quiero saber es de ese reload :3 . Gracias

Comment: Respuesta actualizada ;)

Comment: muchas gracias :3 . algo asi era lo que queria saber